# How to configure RC3 pin as output in PIC16F886?

Tags: microcontroller, microchip, microprocessor, mplab, pic16f

I already used it with a PIC18 and the RC3 pin is working for me, but for the PIC16F886 the 14th pin is described as "[RC3/SCK/SCL](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/40001291H.pdf)", however, in picture 18 it is described as only "RC3".

Any head start / help that someone can provide?

Answer (score 1):

One pin can have alternate functions. RC3 / SCK / SCL means that the pin can be used as SCK (clock) for SPI, or SCL (clock) for I²C.

The default function should be GPIO, so all you should do is to play with the direction register, TRISC (if I remember correctly - it's been 15+ years since I last played with a PIC). Please refer to the datasheet, as always.